# PHP Get object indentifier

Tags: php, sqlite

Hopefully this is an easy one for someone.  Basically I have a bunch of SQLite3Result objects that store cached data inside a class.  I need to be able to reference this data when a method is called with the result as an argument. I thought it would be best to just keep the cache in an array where the key is a unique identifier for the result object.

So, is there anyway to get a unique indentifier for an object?  Like the addressof() function in 'other' languages.  I just need something so that when subsequent calls to a method with the result as an argument I can look up cached data based on that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your cached data is represented by your SQLite results, you could use their primary key identifiers as identifiers for your caches.

A PHP OOP-based alternative is [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php), but this creates a hash for every unique object even if multiple data objects are referenced by the same database row.

Comment: Thank you!  spl_object_hash is exactly what I was after!  I have no idea why that didn't turn up in any of my searches.  I actually do need the hash to be different even if it's for the same database row, table or whatever.  I just need an identifier for each individual object as they all need to work independantly regardless of the SQL side of things.

Comment: @Jamie Carl: Then indeed that's what you need. Glad I helped :)